# How to chunk responses in Play without running out of memory

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I'm iterating over a large data set, with regular calls to `play.mvc.Results.Chunks.Out.write(...)` from within `onReady`.

Because writes happen faster than data is sent to the client, I'll often run out of memory after a while... So what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of Play's Java API in Play at the moment. There is no way in the Java API to get *back pressure* from the client, so it's easy to overwhelm the client. This will be fixed in Play 3 when we provide a better streams API to Java clients, probably based on [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M4/java.html).

If you really need to solve this problem then you may be able to write a small program in Scala based on Play's Enumerators and then wrap it so you can access it from your Java program.

Comment: Yes! The Java API methods should really be returning Promises so that you can wait on the Promise before sending the next bit of data.

Comment: Turns out the heap exhaustion in this case was due to a memory leak in New Relic... Being able to wait before sending more data still seems like a good idea, of course.